# Problems with numpad operators

Tags: interface

I have a problem that's kind of weird. The numpad operation keys (<kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd>) dont work as expected. I cant do the math when transforming objects.

For example hitting <kbd>G</kbd> while object is selected, then <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> doesn't move the object 4 units on the X axis, instead - it moves it 22 units, like if that <kbd>+</kbd> hit was ignored.

I've noticed it when moving from Blender 2.68 to later versions.
(actually after installing 2.68 after the installation of 2.75, the 2.68 also works that way)

Is there anyway to get back the old functionality?

Comment: Are you sure that your NUMPAD is turned ON ?

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov If you mean "NumLock" - yes, it's on.

Comment: I actualy tried myself what you was talking about, I can't do this either nor with Numpad nor with the Alphanumeric Keyboard

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov That's what I supposed to be. Check out my answer - theres some kind of solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blender 2.75, you have to use [expressions](https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/interface/buttons_and_controls.html?highlight=expressions#expressions).

To evaluate any expression, you have to start with <kbd>=</kbd>

In your example: <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The kind of "solution" to this is to press the  <kbd>*</kbd> (star key) on the numpad while in the input mode. 
For example - with object selected pressing <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> will translate the object 4 units on the X axis. The star somehow changes the input mode.

This worked in 2.75a, but not 2.68 - it looks like something got screwed when installing 2.75a. My guess is - it should work from 2.69 onwards.